# Java - get custom LogManager from Logger.getLogger() from other jar?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I had one single project which was using log4j.

But I had to separate my projec in two... So the first one is the "core" one and the other is the app itself.

My custom LogManager is still in the "app-project", but I need to log using my LogManager what's going on in the "core-project".

I want to log everything from my library (core.jar) into my custom log4j.

How can I make this work? Does it works this way? Or should I move my custom LogManager in the core project? If yes, how can I make my app log in the LogManager of the core.jar?

I don't know if I'm clear... here's a drawing:

[image: My goal]

For the moment, in my core, I'm simply doing (**java.util.logging**):

```
Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "This is a log message");
```

I don't know if it's useful to know, but I'm setting my log4j properties programmatically, in my LogManager class, such as (**slf4j.Logger + log4j**)

```
public class LogManager{
    private LogManager(){
        //I set it here
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which `Logger` is that?  Is it the `java.util.logging` one or log4j?

Comment: In the core project, it's java.util.logging! Edited!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `java.util.logging.Logger` to get the log manager, there's a system property you can set, `java.util.logging.manager`, that will replace the default log manager with the class named by that system property.

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html

Of course you need the class path set to your other Jar file where the new log manager class is located.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm not able to access to `java.util.logging.config`? Does `java.util.logging.MemoryHandler.target` would do the same? If I give him the path of my LogManager class?

Comment: Well, your new log manager class would have to handle that.  Write code to look for the config file and instantiate handlers based on its contents.

Comment: Oh I get it! I don't have any config file.. it could help! Thanks for help, I'll see what I can do!